# RethinkDB javascript to java query

Tags: javascript, java, syntax, rethinkdb

I am fairly new to RethinkDB, so I was able to create my query in JavaScript the problem now is to translate this query into the Java language.

Can someone with more experience help me please?

```
r.db('reval').table('measurements').filter({ measurementId: 1478261131038})
              .update(function(measurement){
                  return r.branch(measurement.hasFields('movingObject'), 
                    { movingObject: measurement('movingObject').append({'x': 10, 'y': 40})},
                    { movingObject : [{'x': 0, 'y': 0}]}
                       )})
```

**UPDATE:**

After some help from ... I was able to insert the first object of the array. The problem now is when I want to keep inserting more elements.

I start with this record:

```
{
"from": null ,
"id":  "c94aa215-a47e-4cd0-8f98-1b69d7e93a1d" ,
"measurementId": 1478273740811 ,
"movingObject": null,
"time": null ,
"userObject": null
}
```

After calling this query:

```
    MapObject myArray = new MapObject().with("x", 20).with("y", 80);
    MapObject myArray2 = new MapObject().with("x", 10).with("y", 40);

        HashMap run = r.db("reval").table("measurements")
                .filter(measurement -> measurement
                        .g("measurementId")
                        .eq(1478273740811L))
                .update(measurement ->
                    r.branch(
                            measurement.hasFields("movingObject"), 
                                r.hashMap("movingObject", measurement.g("movingObject").append(myArray)),
                                new MapObject().with("movingObject", myArray2)
                            )).run(connectionFactory.createConnection());
```

The result was this:

```
{
"from": null ,
"id":  "c94aa215-a47e-4cd0-8f98-1b69d7e93a1d" ,
"measurementId": 1478273740811 ,
"movingObject": {
"x": 10 ,
"y": 40
} ,
"time": null ,
"userObject": null
}
```

Now when I want to insert another element into my array (in this example {{"x": 20, "y": 80}}) the Java code gives the following error:

```
{
deleted=0,
inserted=0,
unchanged=0,
replaced=0,
first_error=Expected type ARRAY but found OBJECT.,
errors=1,
skipped=0
}
```

**Can anyone give me some pointer on how to solve this problem, because I think we are very close to the solution.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
r.table("measurements")
                .filter(measurement -> measurement.g("measurementId").eq(1478261131038L))
                .update(measurement -> r.hashMap("movingObject", r.branch(measurement.hasFields("movingObject"), 
                        measurement.g("movingObject").append(r.hashMap("x", 10).with("y", 40)), 
                        r.array(r.hashMap("x", 0).with("y", 0)))));
```

Comment: thanks for the help, I implemented the code you provided (after some alterations). I still have some problems, for further details please check the updated question.

Comment: @Anonymous mb you have to write another question for this?

Comment: No under the section **UPDATE** in the above question the details are listed.